# How to import and reference types from a library in my declaration file

Tags: typescript, .d.ts

## Question

How do I import types from a library in a `.d.ts` declaration file?

## Background

I'm writing a `cf.d.ts` file to hold a custom namespace with general-purpose types for my application. This way, I don't have to import some module everywhere I want to refer to `Foo`

```js
declare namespace CF {
  export type Foo = number
}
```

This works well enough for types that wrap primitives (or other custom types in my declaration files). However, I would now like to refer to types that come from a package that I depend on. In this case, I want to refer to types `Instance` and `IAnyType` from the `mobx-state-tree` package:

```js
declare namespace CF {
  /**
   * Represents the parameters to a query
   */
  export type QueryParams<
    F extends Instance<IAnyType>,
    R extends Instance<IAnyType>,
  > = [F[], R[], number]
}
```

As written, `Instance` and `IAnyType` are inferred to be `any` because TS doesn't know where these types come from. The only way I can get accurate typings on these is to prepend `import('mobx-state-tree').` to every usage of these types:

```js
declare namespace CF {
  /**
   * Represents the parameters to a query
   */
  export type QueryParams<
    F extends import('mobx-state-tree').Instance<import('mobx-state-tree').IAnyType>,
    R extends import('mobx-state-tree').Instance<import('mobx-state-tree').IAnyType>,
  > = [F[], R[], number]
}
```

For obvious reasons, I'd like to avoid this verbosity and import them in a single place in my declaration, and then refer to them, but if I `import { ... } from 'mobx-state-tree'` then any module that refers to the `CF` namespace is unable to see the type `QueryParams`.

Other things I've tried:

- `import type { ... } from 'mobx-state-tree'`
- `/// <reference types="mobx-state-tree" />`
- `import MST = require('mobx-state-tree')` (and then using MST.Instance<...>)

Comment: I'm able to work around this (though, in a way it doesn't feel like an idiomatic way to do it), by declaring a namespace called MST where I re-export the types I'm interested in:
`
declare namespace MST {
  export type Instance = import('mobx-state-tree').Instance
  export type IAnyType = import('mobx-state-tree').IAnyType
}
`

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you've figure this out by now, but the problem with adding an import is that it changes the `d.ts` from a `script` (global) to a `module` (local) declaration. The way to make this work is by wrapping the types in a `declare global`.

```
import type { Instance, IAnyType } from 'mobx-state-tree'

declare global {
  namespace CF {
    /**
     * Represents the parameters to a query
     */
    export type QueryParams<
      F extends Instance<IAnyType>,
      R extends Instance<IAnyType>,
      > = [F[], R[], number]
  }
}
```